# Web-based tool to make analytics from a MySQL database

Tags: web-apps, database, mysql, analytics

I have a hosted MySQL database, where I store several records like registered users and activites. I'm looking for a way to see these information in a more "graphical" way.
For example, I would like to plot a graph with the number of registered users per day.

I know there are a lot of business-intelligence software to do analytics from a database, but I've just seen desktop applications or web applications hosted on the author's website. This forces me to allow remote access of my DB since that software doesn't run directly on my host.

So, this is what I'm looking for: a web application to be installed on my server, so it can read my database as localhost and let me plot relatively simple data, joining tables, columns and so on.
It would be a tool to be used by the backend administrator. Being web-based, I'm expecting a login area but that's is not really important.

See it as something like the [Parse Analytics tool](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/parse-analytics-same-great-taste-now-just-the-way-you-like-it/).

Comment: Would a web application that runs on your server, and query your database server, be OK?

Comment: Yes, it's what I'm asking: _"a web application to be installed on my server, so it can read my database as localhost"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I've found Airbnb's [Caravel](https://github.com/airbnb/caravel), *a data exploration platform designed to be visual, intuitive, and interactive*.

I've tried it in my dedicated server and it looks very powerful. Some features are a bit more complex than others but overall it seems ideal to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/).

It is a Business Intelligence suite that you can host on your own server.

It is free and open source.

1. Install Pentaho on your server.
2. Set up accounts for the people who you want to be able to see the dashboards.
3. Configure a connection with your database. That includes entering the password to your database.
4. Create dashboards that contain charts, maps, pivot tables, graphs, and everything you want. Make them available to the accounts you created at step 2.
5. Now people can see the dashboards without knowing the database password.
6. If you want, you can even configure Pentaho so that people can create their own charts and drill the data themselves, without them ever having to see the database password. They will just reuse the database connection you configured in step 3.

[image: Pentaho web dashboard]
[image: Pentaho]